# How can you dynamically set a schema table name for a ecto model

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a model that I would like to partition across multiple database tables. All the data and functionality will be the same so I would like to use the same module/ecto.model but just have the table it is saved into differ. Further, I won't know until runtime what the table name will be.

Can anyone suggest a way to dynamically set the **SCHEMA** table name?

Comment: For selecting, you can pass a tuple of table name / schema like this: `from p in {"posts2", Post}, where p.id == 1`. For inserting you can pass a table name to `Repo.insert_all("posts2", [...])`, but I'm not sure how to do this with `Repo.insert`.

Comment: @Dogbert thanks, your comment saved me a lot of time tonight!

Answer (score 14):

Most of the functions that expect a schema, also accept a tuple in the form of `{"source", Schema}`, where source is the table name. The source is also properly maintained by structs, so if you select from a particular source, when you update/delete it will resolve to the proper table. There's also `Ecto.put_meta(struct, source: "source")` for annotating already build structs.

Those features were also recently expanded to cover more use cases, you can see more in this issue: [#1797](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/1797#issuecomment-260830415).

Comment: Thanks a lot! `Ecto.put_meta(struct, source: "source")` proved to be extremely helpful while inserting/updating. Is it possible to use the same technique while retrieving the data with the help of `Ecto.Repo.get_by/3`?

Comment: I figured it out. We can pass `{"source", Schema}` as the first argument in `Ecto.Repo.get_by/3`. Thanks for all your help.